# How to measure the 'speed' of a kafka connect connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm working with a Kafka connect sink connector but I want to know the 'speed' or latency in which the connector processes messages, so far I've tried sending lots of messages to the topic it reads from in a short span of time; and eventually it catches up to the number of messages without crashing but I don't know how fast it does this.

Is there any way to measure this?